# How to call a lightning web component from within CPQ quote line editor

Tags: quote, cpq

if anyone knows I want to add a new action on the quote line editor, as you may see in the screenshot I have already modified a button however I need it to call a lightning web component and I don't know which route to use for it or how to make it work, right know the button does nothing if clicked, also not sure if it's possible to be done.

[image: This is the add product action I have modified]

Answer (score 1):

Please support this Idea on Idea Exchange to make this feature listed.

[Idea Exchange link]
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000UItAQAW

Answer (score 0):

From your Custom Action you can call a Visualforce. In your case you need to dynamically create a Lightning cmp when initializing VF page. Code snippet below.

There is field on Custom Action - URL, add a link to your custom VF page so it looks like:

```
/apex/c__MyCustomVisualforcePage
```

it's important to provide `__c` prefix.

You can also reference to this [useful link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321269&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1).

And here is an example of `MyCustomVisualforcePage` where we are dynamically creating  c:CustomLightningCmp:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Opportunity" 
       lightningStylesheets="true" standardStylesheets="false">

<apex:slds />
<apex:includeLightning />

<style>
    .page-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        $Lightning.use("c:quoteApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:CustomLightningCmp",   
            { 
                "aura:id": "productsPage"
            },
            "pageContainer",
            function(cmp, status, errorMessage) {
                console.info('creating component...');
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log('Component created successfully ');
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    throw new Error("Component Custom Error");
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script> 

<div class="slds-scope"> <!-- it's IMPORTANT to have this class here to render page with Lightning styles -->
    <apex:form >
        <div id="pageContainer" class="page-container">
            <!-- c:CustomLightningCmp will be placed here -->
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</div></apex:page>
```